# Route domain to mac address

Tags: networking, router, dns, routing, openwrt

I have router running OpenWrt 21.02.3. I also have a server that connects to this router via Ethernet. Other machines connect via Wifi.

The server is internal, so it's only meant to be accessible from inside my home LAN. Typing IP addresses is annoying, so I decided to give it a domain, say `example.com`. I've been adding `192.168.1.100 example.com` to `hosts` files of each machine for the domain to work. That `example.com` happens to resolve in public DNS is irrelevant to me, I would like all requests to `example.com` on my LAN to effectively be hijacked and sent to my server.

I have found that OpenWRT actually has a feature where I can assign a static lease to this machine. This is nice since now I don't have to configure the server to request a specific IP. But it is still annoying that there has to be the one static IP reserved fo rit.

Instead I would like OpenWRT to automatically send `example.com` requests to this machine, regardless of what IP it happens to have. I can see how this would be possible by identifying the machine on the basis of its MAC address, or its hostname. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Technically that's probably possible, but really, just don't. Use a DHCP reservation or a static IP. // You may also want to use OpenWRT's DNS settings so you don't have to modify every PC's *hosts* file.

Comment: Why exactly is it "annoying" that there has to be one static IP reserved for it? Implementing a flexible solution will be definitely more time-consuming (and probably more annoying) than using network standards by setting a static IP or working with a DHCP reservation. If the IP address can not be set to a static one but the MAC address stays the same using a DHCP reservation to force a static IP is the intended method.

Comment: @DanielB I already have configured the DNS to do so. I assumed that instead of pointing the DNS to an IP and then making the server use that IP, I could just point the DNS directly to the server. But if not, it's not the end of the world I suppose. Just wondering how you would do it.

Comment: @Albin Well for one the DHCP is not working too well for the static lease, which is a separate problem that I'm trying to troubleshoot. Second I'm not sure if creating the static lease in OpenWRT also forbids other machines from receiving that IP. Third, I have to remember to set all these IPs every time I set up a router - though to be fair hopefully I won't have to re-do my OpenWRT set up in the near future.

Comment: @evansrhonda You don't have to remember the individual IP addresses, just assign an IP range that is used for all the static addresses and set the static IP address on the server itself. This way your problem with the lease won't matter anymore either. And yes setting an IP lease prevents the DHCP from giving it to other machines as well. But collisions are always possible if you set up static IPs. In regards to your answer to Daniel: pointing a DNS name to an IP **is** the most direct way of pointing to a server. There is no more direct way unless you "break" the way DNS is supposed to work.